# Create mapper that maps a variable number of members to one

Tags: c#, automapper

I've been successfully using AutoMapper for some time now. All my mappings were fairly easy as they were just mapping one property to another. This little program just maps properties for xml serialization using System.Xml.Serialization.

However, I've come across a situation where I need to map many properties to one property.

I have one object called FieldSample with a property called StatesFoundIn, which I've written to look like this:

```
public class StatesFoundIn
{
    [XmlText]
    public String StateId { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("nation")]
    public String Purpose
    {
        get { return "USA"; }
    }

    public StatesFoundIn(String stateId)
    {
        StateId = stateId;
    }

}
```

Which generates a line of XML that looks like this:

```
<StatesFoundIn nation="USA">NY</StatesFoundIn>
```

The AutoMapper current mapping looks like this:

```
cfg.CreateMap<Plant, FieldSample>()
    .ForMember(d => d.StatesFoundIn, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.State))
```

Now obviously this will only return one result.

If I can write a method that returns an array of states, sometime like "**src.GetAllStates()**" instead of just one like "**src.State**" does, would there be a way to get get the mapper to return a list or array of strings so that my XML output could look sometime like this if there is more than one state?

```
<StatesFoundIn nation="USA">NY</StatesFoundIn>
<StatesFoundIn nation="USA">PA</StatesFoundIn>
<StatesFoundIn nation="USA">WV</StatesFoundIn>
<StatesFoundIn nation="USA">OH</StatesFoundIn>
```

Comment: Is it possible in your design to have FieldSample contain a property of type List<StatesFoundIn> instead of just StatesFoundIn?

Comment: @JohnKurtz well I think that is what is confusing me.  Because, as it works now, StatesFoundIn is class that is basically just used to write an XML element as you see above.  I'm not sure how I'd turn that into a list while maintaining the XML functionality.

Comment: To go the other direction, you could modify StatesFoundIn to hold a list of States: <StatesFoundIn nation="USA"><State>NY</State><State>PA</State></StatesFoundIn>

Comment: @JohnKurtz but how would the automapper (in my line above where it creates the mapping), how would it know that there might be multiple states, and to write every state out to an XML element? I guess, it would require some type of loop?